# How to make that the variables of the first component to not erased when I navigate to another component

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have 2 different component that navigate.

1. I create a invoice, add invoice_number,  invoice_date , description and click Add Product.
2. I add product, and navigate in invoice component. When I navigate in invoice, step 1 is deleted.

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kcuyyb?file=app/hello.component.ts)**

Can you suggest me any idea how to issue this?

Thank you!

Comment: you want same data while navigating back to component?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes, only invoice number, invice data, description

Comment: for that you have to store invoice data to service while navigating to another component and retrieve that on component creation.

Comment: I should not use local storage

Comment: When you move from _add sale_ to _add product_ you are trying to keep the `description` and `invoice_number`. Is the invoice number going to be used as `id`?

Comment: @lealceldeiro okay, invoice_number is different

Comment: Why not just use a shared Service or add the required data as queryparams?

Comment: @site I think I misunderstood this... You are trying to hold the data (`invoice_number`, `invoice_date`, `description`) if you fill any of them and then click in the (unrelated flow) _Add Product_ button and then go back to _add sale_. Is that so?

Comment: Yes correctly. I need to hold data when I `Add product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually angular does not provide a state management system for component, like android do.

So if you want to store state of component, use service to store data.

put data to service while navigating to component B. and retrieve that data while navigating back to component A if exist.

Comment: Can you modify my Demo please?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Dear Ravi, if you can please. In this situation I used and a client id. In this post I add more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51441117/how-to-make-that-the-client-id-selected-of-the-first-component-to-not-erased-whe Many thanx

Comment: check answer, if it does not work then you have to provide demo link