# How to make that the client_id selected of the first component to not erased when I navigate

Tags: angular, typescript

I have 2 different component that navigate in each other.

1. I create a invoice, add some data and select client name and click Add Product.
2. I add product, and navigate in invoice component. When I navigate in invoice, client name is deleted.

For other data in invoice component I solution, but, for client I have a problem.

Create a data service like code below:

```
export class DataService {
  _data = new Map<string, any>();

  setData(key, value) {
    this._data.set(key, value);
  }

  getData(key) {
    return this._data.get(key);
  }

  clear() {
    this._data = new Map<string, any>();
  }
}
```

And in InvoiceComponent write this code:

client: Client[];

```
    {
        let invoice = '';
        if (this.ss.getData('invoice')) {
          invoice = this.ss.getData('invoice');
        }
        let invoicedate = '';
        if (this.ss.getData('invoicedate')) {
          invoicedate = this.ss.getData('invoicedate');
        }
        let notes = '';
        if (this.ss.getData('notes')) {
          notes = this.ss.getData('notes');
        }
        let clientid = '';
        if (this.ss.getData('clientid')) {
          clientid = this.ss.getData('clientid');
        }
        this.addsale = this.fb.group({
          'invoice_number': new FormControl(invoice, [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
          'invoice_date': new FormControl(invoicedate, Validators.required),
          'client_id': new FormControl(clientid, Validators.required),
          'notes': new FormControl(notes, Validators.required),
          'products': this.fb.array([]),
        });
      }
     ngOnInit() {
    this.ws.getAllClients().subscribe(
      client => {
        console.log(client)
        this.client = client;
      }
    );
     }
      saveData() {
        this.ss.setData('invoice', this.addsale.get('invoice_number').value);
        this.ss.setData('invoicedate', this.addsale.get('invoice_date').value);
        this.ss.setData('notes', this.addsale.get('notes').value);
        this.ss.setData('clientid', this.addsale.get('client_id').value);
      }
      onSelect(clientid) {
        this.selectedClient = null;
        for (let i = 0; i < this.client.length; i++) {
         if (this.client[i].client_id === clientid) {
         this.selectedClient = this.client[i];
      }

    }
  }
```

Only client doesn't show , all data show correctly.

For client_id I write this code:

Html code:

```
  <div class="input-field col s4">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>Client Data,</legend>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <select (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="selectedClient.client_id" formControlName="client_id" id="client_id"
          materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="client">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Name :</option>
          <option *ngFor="let item of client" [value]="item.client_id">{{item.clientName}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-field col s12" class="ndryshim">
        No Cel:
        <p>{{selectedClient.contactNo}}</p>
        <br>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-field col s12" class="ndryshim">
        Address:
        <p>{{selectedClient.address}}</p>
        <br>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
```

Any idea please?

Thank you

Change:

I change my html code like this:

```
 <div class="input-field col s4">
           <fieldset>
      <legend>Client Data,</legend>
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <input formControlName="client_id" id="client_id"   matInput placeholder="Select Client*" aria-label="State" [matAutocomplete]="auto"
            autoActiveFirstOption [formControl]="client_id">
          <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayWith" >
            <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="updateClient($event, item.client_id, 'client_id')" *ngFor="let item of filteredOptionsClient | async"
              [value]="item.clientName">
              {{ item.clientName }}
            </mat-option>
          </mat-autocomplete>
        </div>
      <br>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        Phone:
        <span style="color:darkblue">{{selectedClient.contactno}}</span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        Address:
        <span style="color:darkblue">{{selectedClient.address}}</span>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
```

And in ts code I change like this:

```
      filteredOptionsClient: any;
      client_id: FormControl = new FormControl();

       client: Client[];

        {
            let invoice = '';
            if (this.ss.getData('invoice')) {
              invoice = this.ss.getData('invoice');
            }
            let invoicedate = '';
            if (this.ss.getData('invoicedate')) {
              invoicedate = this.ss.getData('invoicedate');
            }
            let notes = '';
            if (this.ss.getData('notes')) {
              notes = this.ss.getData('notes');
            }
            let clientid = '';
            if (this.ss.getData('clientid')) {
              clientid = this.ss.getData('clientid');
            }
            this.addsale = this.fb.group({
              'invoice_number': new FormControl(invoice, [Validators.required, Validators.nullValidator]),
              'invoice_date': new FormControl(invoicedate, Validators.required),
              'client_id': new FormControl(clientid, Validators.required),
              'notes': new FormControl(notes, Validators.required),
              'products': this.fb.array([]),
            });
          }


     ngOnInit() {
      this.cs.getAllClients().subscribe(
      client => {
        this.client = client.map((clients) => {
          this.filteredOptionsClient = this.client_id.valueChanges.pipe(
            startWith(''),
            map(val => this.filterClient(val))
          );
          return new Client(clients);
        });
      }
     );
    }
     filterClient(val: string): Client[] {
      if (val) {
      let filterValue = val.toLowerCase();
      return this.client.filter(client => client.clientName.toLowerCase().startsWith(filterValue));
    }
    return this.client;
  }
     saveData() {
     this.ss.setData('invoice', this.addsale.get('invoice_number').value);
     this.ss.setData('invoicedate', this.addsale.get('invoice_date').value);
     this.ss.setData('notes', this.addsale.get('notes').value);
     this.ss.setData('clientid', this.addsale.get('client_id').value);
       }

     updateClient(ev: any, idd: any, componentid: any) {
         if (ev.isUserInput) {
             if (componentid === 'client_id') {
                this.clientid = idd;
                this.addsale['controls']['client_id'].setValue(ev.source.value);
                } else {
                 console.log('ooops');
                }
              }
           let selectedClient = new Client('')
           this.selectedClient = null;
           for (let i = 0; i < this.client.length; i++) {
           if (this.client[i].client_id === idd) {
           this.selectedClient = this.client[i];
           }
          }
          }
          }
```

Comment: Watch out, writing the `clear` method like this `this._data = new Map<string, any>();` is awkward, because each time you _clear_, you're creating a new object, which is going to take more memory in the client's browser.

Comment: Realy? Please can you suggest any idea?

Comment: Well it really depends on you code, but you can try to flush the data in the map

Comment: Checkout [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/clear): you can do a `this._data.clear()`. But once again, it really depends on your implementation, so check out what's best for you

Comment: PS: don't forget to vote UP Ravi Sevta's answer if you found it useful!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call onSelect from ngOnInit() if client id exist

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.ws.getAllClients().subscribe(
      client => {
        console.log(client)
        this.client = client;

        if (this.ss.getData('clientid')) {
          const clientid = this.ss.getData('clientid');
          onSelect(clientid);
        }
      }
    );
 }
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, can you ask me any idea please, how to solve this problem when I change code like in post. Is the same problem. Thank you!

Comment: I have this demo please https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9sijka-qvvpn3?file=app/autocomplete-display-example.ts Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Ravi please, can you ask me any idea how to solve this? Please I need you help!